# Best way to fix "No manual entry for byte\;type\=a" when try to seek kotlin bytecode in intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, bytecode

Step to reproduce

1. on *.kt press command+shift+a for view bytecode

btw,

> Show Kotlin Bytecode

is working properly but broken on

> Show Bytecode

(which I guess it will show java or java bytecode)

[image]

2. select Show Bytecode then got this error

[image]

3. But then when press command+shift+a got this error again and again

[image]

In the beginning I restart the ide and the same error occurs

Then I realised if I press windows then the error gone...
[image]

Answer (score 156, accepted):

MacOs 10.14.4 update enables system shortcut Shift-Cmd-A
Workaround:

- Open "System Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Services"
- Disable "Search man Page Index in Terminal" (or change the keybinding)

Comment: thanks man, I wish I could pin your answer

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: This is under Text and not Terminal in Big Sur.

Comment: Worked for me. Now I am curious how do you know this specific thing :/

Comment: Thanks, man, this was bugging me so hard...

Comment: How do we re-upvote stuff?   If we get helped by the same answer across multiple years there should be an opportunity to recognize it

Comment: @DhirajHimani  If he did it like me it would  be by exhaustively searching _MacOS_ settings. It's no picnic.

Comment: latest place its exits is `system prefereces | keyboard | shortcut | services | text `